# How to get difference between 2 dates in PostgreSQL with TIMESTAMPDIFF?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get it as:

```
SELECT * FROM "Employee" WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', "BirthDate", "HireDate");
```

but I get the next error:

```
ERROR:  function timestampdiff(unknown, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "Employee" WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF('YEAR', "BirthD...
                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've found  another way to get difference between 2 dates but in my instructions it says that I have to get it via `TIMESTAMPDIFF`.
Can someone help me where to look and how to fix my error?

Comment: `"HireDate" - "BirthDate"` There is no `timestampdiff` in Postgres - whatever those instructions are, they are clearly for a different DBMS product. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you mean to switch places? I've tried it also and I got the same error

Answer (score 3):

you can use minus operator

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM (HireDate)-(BirthDate)) AS DateDifference
```

Example `select date '2001-10-01' - date '2001-09-28'`

[DEMO IN FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7a8724c00fa34630f53c98331d22fb97)

[PostGrey Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Interesting.  This works with `-`, but it doesn't work with `age()`.

Comment: with age , date_part('year', age("BirthDate", "HireDate"))

Comment: so how I understood there is no TIMESTAMPDIFF in PostgreSQL, right?
By the way, thanks for the answer!